# Full Calendar multiple background events not rendering

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I am using background events as holidays in fullcalendar. I am fetching events from the database like this

```
 events: [
        @foreach($events as $in)
            {

                id: '{{$in["id"]}}',
                title: '{{$in["name"]}}',
                start: '{{$in["interventionTime"] or ''}}',
                end: '{{$in["interventionTime"]}}', 
                room: '{{$in["room"]}}',
                repeat: '{{$in["repeat"]}}',
                limit: '{{$in["limit"]}}',
                detail: '{{$in["detail"]}}',
                @if($in['holiday'] == 1)
                rendering:  'background',
                backgroundColor:  '#fb0b0b',
                @endif

            },
        @endforeach
```

Everything is coming fine. I see only background events with this color `backgroundColor:  '#fb0b0b',`

But problem starts when I try to detect background events like this

```
   dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')) {
            alert('You cannot create intervention on a holiday');
            return false;
        }
   }
```

Only last background events get detected others do not. I am confused background color is applying to every background events but `rendering:  'background',` is applying only to the last event.
Please help.

Comment: `if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')) {
    alert('holiday);
 }`. Where are you running this code? What does `jsEvent` represent? It's not clear. Also, what are you actually trying to achieve? It's possible that this isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: Maybe its not the best way. I am trying to make some days as holiday. There is no option in full calendar to do that. So I am creating a background event to make it as a holiday. That JsEvent is coming from this
`dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')) {
                alert('You cannot create intervention on a holiday');
                return false;
            }
}`

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to stop users creating events which overlap your background events?

If so, then firstly, don't use `dayClick` for creating events - this should be done by handling the "select" callback, which detects user selection and allows them to drag the mouse across the calendar to indicate the specific time period they want the event for. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/.

Once you do that, this enables you to easily prevent users from adding events over the top of background events, or any other events, by setting the `selectOverlap` option:

```
selectOverlap: false
```

If you want to allow overlaps with other events, but just not background events, then you can put a callback there instead of simply `false`:

```
selectOverlap: function(event) {
   return event.rendering !== 'background';
}
```

This runs once for every event which is overlapped by the user's selection, and checks that the event being overlapped is not a background event before allowing the selection to go ahead.

The advantage here over your method is it gives you access to the actual event *object*, not the HTML element into which it was rendered, and therefore you can inspect all of its properties, including the "rendering" one which tells you whether it's a background event or not.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/ for details.

Comment: Not working. What I need is a way to detect background event. Unfortunetly this code `jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')` detects only a part of date box. Let's say if I click on bottom of the box then this will detect background event but if I click uper side of the date box then it will not detect background class `c-bgevent`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Errors? Unexpected behaviour? Did you set `selectable: true` to allow users to select areas of the calendar? (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectable/). The way you were doing it before is unreliable and not recommended. This method _will_ work if you configure it properly.

Comment: Our of interest, did you manage it by using my suggestion, or another way?